# Find all ids from list in another list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list containing models where each model has a number.

Now I'd like to search another list containg other models where each model could potentially have the number from the first list.

This is how my models look:

```
public class Task 
{
   int AddressId; //foreign key
}

public class Address
{
   int Id; //primary key
}
```

Now I have a list of addresses and a list of tasks.
I'd like to filter my list of tasks to only those tasks where the AddressId is inside my addresses list.

How would my linq look like?

```
result = tasks.Where(t => t.AddressId == ???)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `Join`

```
from m in model1s
join n in model2s on m.Id equals n.Fk
select n
```

To get them into arrays, if you don't know:

```
var model1s = new[] { model1A, model1B, model1C };
var model2s = new[] { model2A, model2B, model2C };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GroupJoin to avoid duplicates:

```
result = from l2 in list2
         join l1 in list1 on l2.FK equals l1.Id into g 
         select l2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice the `AddressId` must be public (however it is not recommended to have public fields so you may change it to a property) so you can do this:

```
 var yourList = addressList.Select(i => i.Id).Distinct();

 taskList.Where(i => yourList.Contains(i.AddressId));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>{new Task(2), new Task(3), new Task(5)};
List<Address> addrList = new List<Address>{new Address(1), new Address(3), new Address(2)};

var result = taskList.Where(x => addrList.Select(y => y.Id).Contains(x.AddressId));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one more alternative I often like to use:

I u could also use a `HashSet<T>` instead of `List<T>` then you could use the [**IntersectWith** Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb293080%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or **[Intersect  Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/bb918911%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)** which makes a more smooth code:-)

so you would have

```
var result = items1.Intersect(items2)
```